# Contentful getEntries by multiple content_types

Tags: javascript, contentful, contentful-management

Can we get all entries by providing multiple content_types:

I have the following code which can only get all entries by one content_type:

```
cf_space.getEntries({content_type: "contentTypeId"}).then(function(contentTypes){

});
```

But can we do like getting multiple entries by providing comma separated entryIds:

```
var entryIds = "id1,id2";
cf_space.getEntries({'sys.id[in]': entryIds}).then(function(entries) {              
});
```

I need to get all entries of each content_type.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible. You'll have to do two separate requests.

Comment: there is a problem in that if i have more than 20 content_types and i want to get entries of each content_type.. then there is too many requests error occurs.

Comment: @maverickosama92 Did you found any solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @dup.titung no I had to call one by one to get entries back then. Haven't checked since then maybe they had added some solution in the latest contentful js SDK.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using the following.

`sys.contentType.sys.id[in]=[content_type1],[content_type2],...`

See https://www.contentfulcommunity.com/t/how-to-query-on-multiple-content-types/473 for details.